# How to install Python (any version) in Windows when you've no admin privileges?

Tags: python

The "NO ADMIN PRIVILEGES" part is key. I need to install Python but I do not have access to it in order to run the installation in a proper way. I'm also behind a firewall, so the "pip" option is quite limited.

Could you help me figure this out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678702/install-python-2-6-without-using-installer-on-win32 maybe?

Comment: The latest Windows 10 May 2019 edition (4 years later) considerably simplify the installation process. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56500630/6309)

Answer (score 72):

From the Python [website](https://www.python.org/getit/), download the MSI version of Python you wish to install.

Then open your command prompt and use this command:

```
msiexec /a python-2.7.10.msi /qb TARGETDIR=C:\python27
```

Substitute `python-2.7.10.msi`, if you downloaded Python 3 and adjust your `TARGETDIR` to where you want it to go.

The `/qb` flag will give you a small dialog progress bar.

Comment: Can you explain how this works? is it to do with /a?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2684631/154770) explains a bit further. Also see the official docs on [Administrative Installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367541(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: The Python 3 installer is not a MSI file.

Comment: I then had to run `python -m ensurepip` to install `pip` into the `Scripts` directory.

Comment: I could not find an msi package for python 3.8 https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/

Comment: @jerik You can install from the `.exe` since python 3.7 (I think). Look at the answers below.

Answer (score 37):

I downloaded embeddable zip file from the site. Extracted it to the folder of my choice. Then added that folder in the windows path variable (using setx). It worked for me. Well this install only python and not the other packages like pip etc.

Later I found better and simpler way with Python 3.7.0 version for windows.

1. Download windows installer exe.
2. Run the exe.
3. Screen will be shown to chose the installation option.
4. Uncheck "install for all users" option.
5. Go for the custom installation.
6. On next screen specify the directory path for which your user have
   full access on the computer.
7. Uncheck "create shortcuts for installed application" option.
8. Make sure "Add python to environment variable" option is Unchecked .
9. complete the installation.
10. Add the installation and Script folder path in PATH using setx

This has installed all the default components of python

Comment: uncheck "install for all users"

Comment: Please explain setx in step 10.

Comment: If python is installed at location c:\programs\Python, then path of the script folder should be c:\programs\Python\Scripts. Add these to folders in the path using setx as setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\programs\Python\;C:\programs\Python\Scripts\"

Answer (score 15):

As the comment states: "uncheck '[Install launcher] for all users'"..

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I suggest you use Anaconda ([open source edition](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads)).

> Anaconda is a completely free Python distribution (including for
> commercial use and redistribution). It includes more than 300 of the
> most popular Python packages for science, math, engineering, and data
> analysis.

One great feature of Anaconda is that it **installs to your home folder**, to which you should have write access.

It ships with a `conda` script that let's you install packages too.

Keep in mind that you will not be able to add it to the System `PATH`, though you can try to add it to your user `PATH`. If you can not add it to either, you will have to manually specify the full path to the python executable to run scripts from the command line.

Comment: Even if access via the GUI is blocked, you can usually edit the *user* environment variables (including `PATH`) by running: `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest you try using [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It can be installed to a local user folder without requiring admin permissions.

With this, you also get a quite nice package management `conda`.

Comment: How does this solve the problem of having no admin privileges? I'm not sure your answer solves the OP's problem.

Comment: In our company environment this installer is working well, since it is only extracting the files in a user-writeable location and setting up the environment correspondingly.

Comment: Then why don't you expand your answer to include that information? :)

Comment: Yes it does, because you can install it anywhere you want, e.g. into you home directory, so no admin priviliges required

Comment: 1) short question, short answer 2) I'm no anaconda-evangelist and don't know about the background details so much I would provide better info than the homepage does 3) some background info is nice, especially on controversial topics, but this was quite straight for me.

Answer (score 3):

With Windows 2010 edition May 2019, you won't have to execute a msi setup or download an Anaconda edition or go to the python website.

- Windows has a `python.exe` and `python3.exe` already pre-installed
- those commands will get you directly to the Microsoft Store!

Example: [Python 3.9](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/python-39/9p7qfqmjrfp7?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), which installs `python` and puts `python` on the path for the current user. So, no need for admin privileges.

There is a discussion about this on the [Talk Python To ME podcast #191 with Steve Dower](https://talkpython.fm/episodes/show/191/python-s-journey-at-microsoft) from Dec. 2018.

See more at "[Who put Python in the Windows 10 May 2019 Update?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/)" from the same [Steve Dower](https://twitter.com/zooba) (also [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891/zooba)):

> This version of Python is fully maintained by the community, installs easily on Windows 10, and automatically makes common commands such as `python`, `pip` and `idle` available (as well as equivalents with version numbers python3 and python3.7, for all the commands, just like on Linux).

[image: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/wp-content/uploads/sites/12/2019/05/Python_After-1024x449.png]

---

Note: [not2qubit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1147688/not2qubit) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876657/how-to-install-python-any-version-in-windows-when-youve-no-admin-privileges/56500630#comment136931850_56500630) that:

> The MS Store python install is *not* recommended, as you will have no control of where things go, `PATH`'s etc.
> Unless you are a first timer of Python, do it manually from the MSI (or `winget -i`) installer and use the Customize installation option.
>
> You may want to check `py` launcher option if you want to be able to click a `py` file to run.
> This is also *not* standard way to run a python file, unless you're creating an entire app.
> In addition, this check box will make all `*.py` files executed using the default python file opener `py.exe`, instead of an editor like (np++, VSCode, etc.), for example.

Comment: I wanted to comment that I'd rather not go the the MS store. But then I realized how high your reputation is and if I might change my attitute because of this.

Comment: @bomben Thank you. I just realized the Python 3.7 link was obsolete. I have updated and restored the link.

Comment: The MS Store python install is not recommended as you will have no control of where things go, PATH's etc. Unless you are a first timer of Python, do it manually from the MSI (or winget -i) installer and use the `Customize installation` option. You may want to check `py launcher` option if you want to be able to click a py file to run. This is also not standard way to run a python file, unless you're creating an entire app. In addition, this check box will make all `*.py` files executed using the default python file opener `py.exe`, instead of an editor like (np++, VSCode etc.) , for example.

Comment: @not2qubit Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck 'Install for all user' when the installation starts. Rest will be taken care by Python-3.
I'm using Python-3.7.6 with this method.

This installation method will automatically updates current user's path for Python. But the application name will be `py` instead of `python`. The user has to handle environment variables if he wants to use `pip` or `python` commands.

Comment: If you check the box to update environment variables, you will have python and pip in your path.

Comment: @Holt can you provide the example what kind of path needed for pip an python in environment variables ?

Comment: @sathya With python 3.8.1, you only need `Python38` and `Python38\Scripts` where `Python38` is the installation folder of python. With the 3.8.1 `.exe` installer, I did not have to update the path manually, the installer did it for me (I had to check the relevant box).

Answer (score 1):

Try installing off the Microsoft Store