# Azure DevOps pipeline microsoft hosted image with specific Python version

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I want to make use of Python 3.4 x86 as my build target. Microsoft hosted agents don't have that as an [option - 3.5 is the lowest version 3x branch](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2016-Readme.md).

Can I just install python during run process - still use Microsoft hosted agent but with python version I like?

The UsePythonVersion doesn't install it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Hosted agent `vs2017-win2016` and we can see that the Python version installed by the agent does not contain `Python 3.4`

Check the [task prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version?view=azure-devops#prerequisites):

- A Microsoft-hosted agent with side-by-side versions of Python installed, or a self-hosted agent with Agent.ToolsDirectory configured (see FAQ).

This task will fail if no Python versions are found in Agent.ToolsDirectory. Available Python versions on Microsoft-hosted agents can be found [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2016-Readme.md#python).

As a workaround, we should install the Python 3.4 via command line and then use the task Use Python version to specify the Python version. Check this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#installing-without-ui) for more details.

**Update1**

It seems that we cannot install 3.4 in the hosted agent.

TEST1 install python via power shell script:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "{URL}" -OutFile "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/{python install file .exe}"

$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/{python install file .exe} /quiet InstallAllUsers=0 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0
```

But cannot found python 3.4 exe file in the [download website](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.0/).

TEST2 install the python via extension.

Extension: [Python build tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stevedower.python)

Task: Install Python on Windows

According to the [json file](https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/python/index.json), we can see that 3.5.2 is the lowest version.

Comment: Hello. I carefully read the documentation. For Microsoft hosted agent, there doesn't appear to be a task to install Python. Is the idea that using PowerShell or CMD task I should download python MSI and install manually? The FAQ link you shared points to self hosted agent.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Konrads, Yes, the FAQ is points to self hosted agent, I want to share the first with you: A Microsoft-hosted agent with side-by-side versions of Python installed. We need to have this python version and then we could use the task to specify the version.

Comment: About install python via power shell or cmd, you could check this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52578838/13903626) and then kindly share the result here.

Comment: Hi @Konrads, It seems that we cannot do this, check the update1

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Exe isn’t there but msi’s are. They take same options as EXE I believe

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could Accept it as an Answer , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: Hey. Not sure where did we land on this. I tried for a while to install the msi  without much success using the powershell route - no log written, silently fails. I don’t suppose there is a way to take the hosted image and fire it up as a Azure VM to debug?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a customized agent You need to add an environment for AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY and a python folder structure (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=871498).
In my case, I did in docker file used to generate the agent.

```
ENV AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY="/AGENT_DEVOPS"
RUN mkdir /AGENT_DEVOPS
RUN mkdir /AGENT_DEVOPS/Python

# python 3.8
RUN mkdir /AGENT_DEVOPS/Python/3.8.0
RUN apt-get install python3.8-venv
RUN python3.8 -m venv /AGENT_DEVOPS/Python/3.8.0/x64
RUN touch /AGENT_DEVOPS/Python/3.8.0/x64.complete

# python 3.7
RUN mkdir /AGENT_DEVOPS/Python/3.7.5
RUN apt-get install python3.7-venv
RUN python3.7 -m venv /AGENT_DEVOPS/Python/3.7.5/x64
RUN touch /AGENT_DEVOPS/Python/3.7.5/x64.complete
```